# Which disk did I boot from?

Tags: hard-drive, startup

I have multiple hard drives, each containing various partitions, with various bootable OS X versions on them.

This Apple support link, despite the title, [Determine which disk started up your Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/determine-which-disk-started-up-your-mac-mh19543/mac), just tells me which hard disk is selected for a *normal* boot:

> 1. On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences.
> 2. Click Startup Disk.
>
>    Your selected startup disk is shown at the top of the preferences
>    pane.

However, if I booted whilst holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and selected a different disk, the **Startup Disk** control panel doesn't reflect which disk I *actually* booted from.

**Disk Utility** doesn't appear to *explicitly* show this information either, although it *seems to imply* that the active system disk is the pre-selected disk - upon opening the application.

How can I quickly determine which disk my Mac booted from (via the UI or command line)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the menu bar, select `About this Mac`, as shown below.

[image]

You should then get a popup window showing the startup disk, as shown below.

[image]

You can also get the startup disk by entering the command given below.

```
diskutil info / | grep "Volume Name"
```

Example output is given below.

```
   Volume Name:              Marlin
```

The version of macOS can be found in the by using the command below.

```
sw_vers
```

Example output is given below.

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.6
BuildVersion:   17G14042
```